# Show that $\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}}B }{\mathrm{d} A^{2}}> 0 $ if $U''<0$.

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, economics, implicit-differentiation

Given, $A = W_0 - L_0 + I - qI$, $B = W_0 - qI$, and $EU = p U(A) + (1-p) U(B) = k$, where $k$ is a constant.

$\frac{\mathrm{d} B}{\mathrm{d} A}\bigg|_{}^{EU=k} = \frac{\frac{\partial EU }{\partial A}}{\frac{\partial EU}{\partial B}} = \frac{- p U'(A)}{(1-p) U'(B)}.$

The second derivative seems really complicated,as $A$ and $B$ are not separable.

I think I may have to do implicit differentiation, so I would appreciate some help on that.

**Edit:** $$\frac{\mathrm{d^{2}}B }{\mathrm{d} A^{2}} = -\frac{\frac{\partial^2 EU }{\partial A^2}}{\frac{\partial^2 EU }{\partial B^2}} = -\frac{- p U''(A)}{(1-p) U''(B)} > 0.$$

I seem to be getting the right answer, but is my second derivative correct?

Comment: What are $M,N$? You need to elaborate your question a little.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, that was a typo and I fixed it.

Comment: @ OP: please see my edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this appears to be an economics problem, I think an intuition approach is appropriate: suppose that $A$ goes up then $U'(A)$ goes down because $U'$ is decreasing. Moreover, $A\uparrow$ means $I\uparrow$ so $B$ decreases. This means $U'(B)$ goes up. Putting these together, you see that
$$
\frac{p U'(A)}{(1-p) U'(B)}
$$
goes down. Putting back the negative sign
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} B}{\mathrm{d} A}\bigg|_{}^{EU=k} = \frac{- p U'(A)}{(1-p) U'(B)}
$$
goes **up**. In other words, $\frac{dB}{dA}$ is increasing in $A$, which is what you want.

---

**Edit**: A more rigorous approach: differentiate w.r.t. $A$
$$
k=p U(A)+(1-p)U(B)\implies 0=p U'(A)+(1-p)U'(B)\frac{dB}{dA}.
$$
Differentiate w.r.t. $A$ again
$$
0=p U''(A)+(1-p)U'(B)\frac{d^2B}{dA^2}+(1-p)U''(B)\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2
$$
from which you have
$$
\frac{d^2B}{dA^2}=-\frac{1}{(1-p)U'(B)}\left[p U''(A)+(1-p)U''(B)\left(\frac{dB}{dA}\right)^2\right]>0.
$$
If you want to get an explicit expression for $\frac{d^2B}{dA^2}$, you can substitute in $\frac{dB}{dA}=-\frac{p U'(A)}{(1-p) U'(B)}$.

Comment: I am okay with the interpretation of the first derivative, but taking the second derivative seems like a hassle.

Comment: You're right, it will be hairy, that's why I would approach the problem like I did above.

Comment: Yes, but for that I have to find the second derivatives, which is the problem. I can show that the second derivative is positive, but I don't know how I'm going to obtain the form. Could you give me an idea on that?

Comment: I've made an edit.

Comment: @ OP: I made an edit too!